# Read Azure Function Setting from Configuration

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am using Azure Functions with Attributes to define functionality.

```
public static class PostPublishTimerTrigger
{
    [FunctionName("PostPublishTimerTrigger")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer,
        TraceWriter log,
        [Queue("post-published")] ICollector<string> postPublishedQueue)
    {
          // Additional code here
    }
}
```

Is there a way to pull the Schedule `0 */5 * * * *` for a configuration setting, be it with `Configuration Manager` or `Environment Variables`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do

```cs
[TimerTrigger("%schedule%")]
```

and then add a setting called `schedule` with value `0 */5 * * * *`

Comment: Would this setting then live in the local.settings.json or AppSettings?

Comment: In `local.settings.json` when you run locally, in portal App Settings when you run in Azure