# How to use configuration values in Azure Function attributes?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have this in-process function:

```cs
[CosmosDBTrigger(
                databaseName: <HERE_EDIT>,
                collectionName: <HERE_EDIT>,
                ConnectionStringSetting = "...",
                LeaseCollectionName = "...",
                LeaseCollectionPrefix = <HERE_EDIT>,
                StartFromBeginning = true
            )]IReadOnlyList<Document> input,
            [EventHub(<HERE>, Connection = <HERE>)] IAsyncCollector<EventData> collector,
            ILogger log)
(...)
```

And I want to use values from the `app settings` or `local.settings.json` so that I can have different values depending on the deployment slot ( to substitute where it says `<HERE>` ).

Is that even possible?

Thanks

--- EDIT ---

As pointed by `AdaTheDev` I can just use the `Connection` prop including the name of the event hub.

But if I wanted to use in the `<HERE_EDIT>` to change the collection in production and the lease prefix is there a common way, that I could also apply to other attributes?

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47121789/4167200. try with this syntax: `%appSettingName%`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For `Connection`, it can be the name of an appsetting. And if that connection string includes the event hub name, that will override the value given explicitly as the EventHubName argument in the attribute.

Refence: [Event Hubs Output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-output?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#connections)

Comment: If I wanted to do the same for the prop `LeaseCollectionPrefix` or `collectionName` of the `CosmosDBTrigger` how would I go about it? (I'll edit the question to include this as well)

Comment: Check out the MS docs - all there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#attributes

Comment: I don't see any mention as to how to use different values depending on the environment.